# CSS First element that does not have a class

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've got a few list items, the first one's with a featured class and the after a while a few without. Withh CSS, I'd like to select the first item in the list *that does not have a featured class*...

The code is as follows:

```
<ul>
<li class="featured"></li>
<li class="featured"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried the following with no effect:

```
ul li:not(.featured):first-child {
  /* Do some stuff here */
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this without resorting to jQuery?

**UPDATE**
The ability does exist to add non-feature classes if that would help. E.g:

```
<ul>
<li class="listing featured"></li>
<li class="listing featured"></li>
<li class="listing"></li>
<li class="listing"></li>
<li class="listing"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `:first-child` is just that: match elements that are the first child of their parents, not "filter the list of things matched by rule parts to the left of this one"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "Adjacent sibling combinator": http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators

```
li.featured + li:not([class="featured"])
```

Comment: Aaah you did just one mistake, you need to use `+` instead of `~` I tweaked your selector, take a look, but +1 from me, it's nice

Comment: Thanks for your remark :) I've edited the code to provide the right selector.

Comment: Great, I just deleted my answer :)

Comment: Brilliant - completely forgot about the adjacent selector!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the great answer by @Cédric Belin - if you wanted to make the CSS backwards compatable you could use the following CSS selectors:

```
ul .featured + li {
    /* some styles */
}

ul li.featured {
    /* some styles */
}
```

Note that the order of the CSS styles is important here as both selectors have the same weighting - so which ever style comes last will be the one that overrides the previous style (due to the cascading nature of CSS)

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ku77T/**

Comment: Fortunately I don't care that much about the "featured" item per se, it's more the first item AFTER the "featured" item :)